# Double nested dynamic module registration - vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

According to the [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) we can dynamically register a nested module in this way:

```
store.registerModule(['nested', 'myModule'], {
  // ...
})
```

And we can access this state using `store.state.nested.myModule`

How do I dynamically register a module nested another layer deep within the first module. IE. How can I make the modules exposed state be instead `store.state.nested.furtherNested.myModule`. Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to register the `furtherNested` module:

```
store.registerModule(['nested', 'furtherNested'], {
  // ...
})
```

And then register the `myModule` module in `furtherNested` by specifying the path in the array like so:

```
store.registerModule(['nested', 'furtherNested', 'myModule'], {
  // ...
})
```

Here's a simple example:

```js
let store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: { 
    nested: {}
  }
});

store.registerModule(['nested', 'furtherNested'], {})

store.registerModule(['nested', 'furtherNested', 'myModule'], {
  state: { foo: 'bar' }
})

console.log(store.state.nested.furtherNested.myModule);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you have `namespaced: true` in all your nested modules otherwise you will have error: "unknown mutation type". So, top level module registration should be like this: `  modules: { 
    nested: {`namespaced: true` }
  }`

Comment: I have found this answer when was searching about nested vuex modules. I missed that part that I need register top level of module first. So, thank you!